# Computer programming in calculation puzzles

Tags: discussion

In a [recent puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48740/number-88-from-the-digits-2-0-1-and-7), 2 of the submissions were computer programs.

Now while I don't have a problem with computer programming, the two submissions used the programs to get around an obvious hurdle in the question.

What then, is stopping this submission:

> Python 3.6.0 code! Try `print(ord('X'))#2017`, which works! You don't even need any numbers!

Or this:

> Again Python 3.6.0! Try this:
>   `def eight(x):return x+7+1`
>   `print(eight(eight(eight(eight(eight(eight(eight(eight(eight(eight(eight(0))))))))))))#2`

They are both *'valid'*, but they aren't really what the asker was looking for.

Where is the line between lateral thinking and defeating the point of the puzzle?

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1334/the-oracle-was-lying-just-stab-them-instead-and-other-creatively-unh (because the question "do these answers _really_ answer the question?" is basically the same here, though in a different mode).